# html to text in PHP

Tags: php

i need bypass all html tags to text, Im sure is there any way to bypass all html tags to text in format html, I ut my example below:

Example:

```
<p style="clear: both;"></p>
```

for

```
&lt;p style="clear: both;"&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

any function? thanks :)

Comment: so you want to encode all of your html?

Answer (score 1):

use `strip_tags` for removing html tags

```
$str = strip_tags("your string");
```

for displaying html tags use `htmlspecialchars`

```
htmlspecialchars("<html>something</html>"); // output <html>something</html>
```

Comment: this removes html tags, I dont need that, i neeed to show html in text format

Comment: @josesanchez It *would* by removing the HTML tags? Can you give an example of "input text" and "wanted output text"?

Comment: this

<p style="clear: both;"></p>

for

&lt;p style="clear: both;"&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

Comment: You mean you want to render the text to html? Like a browser would?

Comment: @josesanchez Accepting answer is good habit, when it helps you.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably searching for [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

```
$str = htmlentities('<p style="clear: both;"></p>');
var_dump($str);
```

or if you want to do it the other way around, use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php):

```
$str = html_entity_decode('&lt;p style="clear: both;"&gt;&lt;/p&gt;');
var_dump($str);
```